# iOS eSim installation flow does not show a custom label settings screen

Tags: ios, swift, entitlements, cellular-network, core-telephony

It seems that the ability to give an eSim a custom label in the installation flow (after programmatically executing`addPlan` with a `CTCellularPlanProvisioningRequest`), has disappeared. At least this does not show up for us. This is confusing for our users because the default label is now set by iOS to 'Travel' or 'Personal' or whatever. And then, when selecting the default line in the screen below, the users choice is confusing:

[image]

Does anybody know how to change this label programmatically or enforce a custom setting screen? The screen I'm referring too looks like this (but it does not show up):

[image]